# Transforming partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transformation, partial-derivative

$13.$ Consider the change of variables

$$x = e^{−s} \sin t,\space y = e^{−s} \cos t, \space \text{such that} \space u(x,y) = v(s,t)$$

(i) Use the chain rule to express $∂v/∂s$ and $∂v/∂t$ in terms of $x$, $y$, $∂u/∂x$ and $∂u/∂y$.

(ii) Find, similarly, an expression for $∂^2v/∂t^2$.

(iii) Hence transform the equation
$$y^2 \frac{∂^2u}{∂x^2} −2xy \frac{∂^2u}{∂x∂y} +x^2 \frac{∂^2u}{∂y^2}=0$$
into a partial differential equation for $v$.

Sorry for the poor formatting, the question is also question $13$ on http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/examples/A3d.pdf

I have done the first parts but it seems that I have gone wrong as I cannot see how they fit together to transform the final equation. All help is appreciated.

[image: my attempt]

Comment: Maybe you can post the answer to the first part so that we can show you where you went wrong or if you are on the correct path..

Comment: I have edited the post with my attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your step 1 is correct. Let's recap it as 
$$v_s = -xu_x-yu_y,\quad v_t = yu_x-xu_y$$
To calculate $v_{tt}$, insert the formula for $v_t$ into itself:
$$v_{tt} = y(yu_x-xu_y)_x-x(yu_x-xu_y)_y $$
This way you are not mixing $xy$ and $ts$ derivatives. The rest of computation is straightforward:
$$v_{tt} = y^2u_{xx}-2xyu_{xy}+x^2 u_{yy} - yu_y - xu_x  $$
The third step should be easy now.